# Best way to linearly step-up MCU output 0-3.3V to 0-5V

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, analog, pwm, output

I am about to move from Arduino to my own MCU platform and am currently looking at the likes of the ARM Cortex M7 and M0+. One of my worries is that these microcontrollers seem to be only capable of outputting 3.3V. I need to send digital, PWM and analog signals scaling up to 5V, for example a throttle signal going from 1 to 4V. What would be the best, most efficient way of doing that?
Thank you!

Comment: There is no single best way, it all depends on the properties of the signal you need

Comment: "Best and efficient" depend on what you value.. simplicity, cost, parts availability, power, ruggedness..?

Comment: one way would be to keep it all digital for transmission and use a serial DAC at the end where you need the analog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Digital

The first step is to make sure you really need 5 V output.  Many digital inputs have a low enough minimum logic high threshold so that 3.3 V is solidly high.

If you really need 5 V logic signals, use *level converters*.  These are small, cheap, and readily available.  They have a split power supply.  You power one side from the 3.3 V supply and connect it to 3.3 V logic, and power the other side from 5 V and connect it to 5 V logic.

Sometimes the requirements are simple so that this can be achieved with a single transistor.  But, given the level of your question, the best answer is simply "use level converters".

### Analog

Converting from 5 V to 3.3 V is easily done with a *voltage divider*, which is made from two resistors.

For converting from 3.3 V to 5 V, again, first make sure that it's really needed.  If it is, this can be done with a opamp in classic positive gain configuration.  That means signal into the + input, and two resistors that divide the output voltage into the - input.

Comment: FWIW, converting digital signals with simple voltage dividers (R only) is also quite feasible as long as need to *decrease* the voltage.

Comment: Do you suggest a specific opamp or opamp configuration for converting 3.3V to 5V without using a separate power supply >5V? For example, LM324 has a dropout voltage of 1.3V, so if you supply 5V to LM324, you can't get 5V output.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you have a 5V power supply for the circuit that still requires 5V so, just use a TTL/CMOS buffer chip powered from the 5V rail. The 3V3 signal from the 3V3 powered device will almost certainly output a voltage higher than the 2V high threshold needed on the buffer's input and its CMOS output will be 5V.

The [74AHCT1G32GW/T1](http://uk.farnell.com/nxp/74ahct1g32gw-t1/74ahct-single-gate-smd-74ahct1g32/dp/1085248) is a dual input OR gate that does this but you can get buffers in the same range (such as the SN74AHCT1G125).

If you need an analogue signal amplifier use a rail-to-rail opamp with the appropriate gain setting resistors: -

[image]

As for the type of op-amp, this is speed and accuracy dependent but the OPA333 springs to mind for low speed and the AD8605 springs to mind for higher speed.

Comment: There's no apparent reason why digital logic should be used. A pure, one-directional buffer IC like 74HCT125 is probably a better choice.

Comment: @Lundin - Note that I said use a buffer from the same range.

Comment: In this case for a gain of 1.5 if I take Rg=1kohm and Rf=1.5kohm, would it be ok?

Comment: For this op-amp circuit, gain = 1 + Rf/Rg therefore Rg should be twice Rf.